# kubernetes: pods cannot connect to internet

Tags: kubernetes, proxy, calico

I cannot connect to internet from pods. My kubernetes cluster is behind proxy.
I have already set `/env/environment` and `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http_proxy.conf`, and confirmed that environment variables(`http_proxy`, `https_proxy`, `HTTP_PROXY`, `HTTPS_PROXY`, `no_proxy`, `NO_PROXY`) are correct.
But in the pod, when I tried `echo $http_proxy`, answer is empty. I also tried `curl -I https://rubygems.org` but it returned `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: rubygems.org`.
So I think pod doesn't receive environment values correctly or there is something I forget to do what I should do. How should I do to solve it?

I tried to `export http_proxy=http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx; export https_proxy=...`.
After that, I tried again `curl -I https://rubygems.org` and I can received header with 200.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set proxy settings (http\_proxy variables) for kubernetes (v1.11.2) cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53173487/how-to-set-proxy-settings-http-proxy-variables-for-kubernetes-v1-11-2-cluste)

Comment: `Could not resolve host: rubygems.org` is a DNS issue. You might be connected to internet. Have you tried something like 8.8.8.8?

Comment: I tried, but cannot resolve host. Pod has no `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY`, so It seems to use what written in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Answer (score 1):

What I see is that you have wrong  `proxy.conf` name.
As per [official documention](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/) the name should be `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf`and not `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http_proxy.conf`.

Next you add proxies, reload daemon and restart docker, as mentioned in provided in comments [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53173487/how-to-set-proxy-settings-http-proxy-variables-for-kubernetes-v1-11-2-cluste)

`/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http_proxy.conf`:

Content:

```
    [Service]
    Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://x.x.x:xxxx"
    Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=http://x.x.x.x:xxxx"

# systemctl daemon-reload
# systemctl restart docker
```

Or, as per [@mk_ska answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53209308/9929015) you can

> add http_proxy setting to your Docker machine in order to forward
>   packets from the nested Pod container through the target proxy server.
>
> For Ubuntu based operating system:
>
> Add export http_proxy='http://:' record to the file
>   /etc/default/docker
>
> For Centos based operating system:
>
> Add export http_proxy='http://:' record to the file
>   /etc/sysconfig/docker
>
> Afterwards restart Docker service.

Above will set proxy for all containers what will be used by docker engine

Comment: I tried to do this, but cannot solve the problem... In the pod, it seems not to inherit environment variables. Also I found another problem (if I expose `http_proxy`, pods cannot resolve inner server name) so I'm going to close this question and seek another way. Anyway, thank you for your help! ;)

Comment: You need to use no_proxy for IP ranges of your cluster. You dont want that traffic routed through your proxy